# How to make pause between figures using subfloat figure (Beamer)?

Tags: latex, beamer

My problem is when I put \pause at the end of each figure, the figures change their numbering.
For example (my first figure is (a) when I call the second figure, the first figure change from (a) to (h), and the second figure is (i). How can I solve that problem?

Comment: You could use an uncover environment. If you'd like to see an example how to do this, please add a compilable [mre] to your question.